# Algebraic manipulation help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm self-teaching geometric progressions and was asked to find the sum to $n$ terms of $$x + 1 + \frac{1}{x} + \cdots$$ so I used the formula $$\frac{a(r^n - 1)}{r - 1}$$ with $a = x$ and $r = \frac{1}{x}$, and I arrived at $$\frac{x^{1-n} - x}{x^{-1} - 1}$$ The answer in the book is $$\frac{x^n-1}{x^{n-2}(x - 1)}$$

I cannot see how to manipulate my answer to get to the one in the book (though I know they're equivalent as [Wolfram Alpha says so](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E%281-n%29-x%29/%28x%5E-1-1%29=%28x%5En-1%29/%28x%5E%28n-2%29%28x-1%29%29)). Hope someone can show me how to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s a computational verification.

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{1-n}-x}{x^{-1}-1}&=\frac{x^{1-n}-x}{x^{-1}-1}\cdot\frac{x^{n-1}}{x^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{1-x^n}{x^{n-2}-x^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{1-x^n}{x^{n-2}\left(1-x\right)}\\
&=\frac{1-x^n}{x^{n-2}\left(1-x\right)}\cdot\frac{-1}{-1}\\
&=\frac{x^n-1}{x^{n-2}(x-1)}
\end{align*}$$

Had I been confronted with your result, however, I’d automatically have turned negative exponents into positive ones and then simplified the four-storey fraction:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{1-n}-x}{x^{-1}-1}&=\frac{\frac1{x^{n-1}}-x}{\frac1x-1}\\
&=\frac{\frac1{x^{n-1}}-x}{\frac1x-1}\cdot\frac{x^{n-1}}{x^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{1-x^n}{x^{n-2}-x^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{1-x^n}{x^{n-2}(1-x)}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Whether I leave it like that or flip the differences around depends on whether I expect to be dealing with $x<1$ (leave it) or $x>1$ (flip it).

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @PeteUK: My pleasure!